# Get address from google api search

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-props

I am trying to get an address user types within the google api search for my component.
I am using **Map with a SearchBox** example from https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#usage--configuration

And exporting this code example component

```
export default MapWithASearchBox;
```

In another component I have a form, where user submits data. 
User search for a location by putting address and the address is found and shown in the map.
But I cannot get this address details and save them in my state.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
     data: {
       address: ""
     }
   };
render() {
    return(
      <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} loading={loading}>
          <MapWithASearchBox />
        <Button primary>Submit</Button>
      </Form>
    )
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to get it and update.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to a specific problem you've got by following the guidelines how to create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: okay, I did as you said